# What are 'separate items resourced by treaty' all about?

Tags: united-states, tax-treaty

In the United States under Section 904 what are 'separate items resourced by treaty' all about? What are good examples of such? What is this good for?

> (6)Separate application to items resourced under treaties
> (A)In general
> If—
> (i)without regard to any treaty obligation of the United States, any item of income would be treated as derived from sources within the United States,
> (ii)under a treaty obligation of the United States, such item would be treated as arising from sources outside the United States, and
> (iii)the taxpayer chooses the benefits of such treaty obligation,
> subsections (a), (b), and (c) of this section and sections 907 and 960 shall be applied separately with respect to each such item.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally used to apply treaty provisions on income that would otherwise be sourced to the US, or several other different use cases, none of which is applicable to your case of New Zealand ignoring capital losses for the purposes of income tax calculation. If you want to see more details, read [this article](https://answerconnect.cch.com/document/arp10303925a27c571000a48a90b11c18cbab02a/federal/irc/explanation/items-resourced-under-treaties).

Comment: Hm. I was thinking that gains on capital are 'gains on disposition of property', and resourced by amended Article 13, for essentially, property that is not real property.

Comment: I could well be wrong as I'm not really sure where 'sourced' and 'resourced' are defined, and how you know if a treaty resources them or not.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith looking at your comments in the other answer, you may have misunderstood how to source your income. Capital income on intangibles sourced per residency, so unless you sold real estate in New Zealand - if you live in the US it's sourced to the US and is not foreign income at all.